# VBA Macro: Paste underneath last cell in column with variable range

Tags: excel, vba

Title isn't the best so here a an overview.

I'm using VBA to copy select columns from one workbook to another, as what will be part of a larger automated program.

On the Workbook I am copying from, there are different sheets containing a "Stock Number" column. When pasting into my other workbook, I am trying to get these columns to merge into 1 single column (pasting below the last entry from the first sheet and so on).

Here is my current code:

```
Sub import_adam_article()

Windows( _
    "copyfrom.xlsx" _
    ).Activate
Columns("F:G").Select
Selection.Copy
Windows("pasteinto.xlsx").Activate
Columns("A:A").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste

Windows( _
    "copyfrom.xlsx" _
    ).Activate
Columns("N:N").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Windows("pasteinto.xlsx").Activate
Columns("C:C").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste

Rows("1:1").Select
Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp

NextRow = Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row + 1

Windows( _
    "copyfrom.xlsx" _
    ).Activate
Columns("F:G").Select
Selection.Copy
Windows("pasteinto.xlsx").Activate
Range("A" & (NextRow)).Select
ActiveSheet.Paste


[A:C].Select
With Selection
    .NumberFormat = "General"
    .Value = .Value
End With  
End Sub
```

The difficulty is that the amount of Stock Numbers will change every new file that comes through, so it needs to be able to adjust to varying amounts.

I can't seem to find a way to make it work and I've tried searching for answers elsewhere.

EDIT: The current issue with the code that it is selecting the next empty row to paste into, but only that cell, not a variable length down as required by the copyfrom column.

Comment: Your first priority should be [getting rid of Select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba)

Comment: I am aware of this, however this is not my question.

Comment: You need to identify your worksheet object. Also, when you paste you have to recalculate your `NextRow`

Comment: @GMalc Thank you, please could you explain what you mean by this? Sorry, just not experienced in VBA. Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [VBA Copying data from one workbook to another using lastrow ranges](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56971952/vba-copying-data-from-one-workbook-to-another-using-lastrow-ranges)

Comment: @Damian thank you though It isn't clear that that is the same issue exactly. I'm struggling to understand the linked question. Does this copy a column, then paste that entire column into a new column underneath existing data (of which that row destination will change each time)

Comment: Your paste should be written something like this `Workbooks("pasteinto").Sheets("Sheet Name").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Paste` which will reset the lastrow for each paste. BUT that won't fix all your problems because you will need to `LOOP` thru each worksheet in  `Workbooks("Copyfrom")` and copy each column range, as your question states that you want to "get these columns to merge into 1 single column".   Per @Nacorid  `Select`, `Windows`, and `Activate` are poor coding practices, and should be avoided.

Comment: It should be your question because you could probably reduce that code to about 3 lines!

Comment: While I appreciate the enthusiasm about cleaning the code, as stated, I know full well it needs changing. The code is from a macro recording to act as a placeholder to give context to a problem I did not know the answer to. Thank you to @GMalc who has given the best information so far and actually trying to answer the question.