# VBA copying data from one workbook to main workbook table

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to copy data from one WB to another (using MacOS if it makes a difference). Currently, my code is:

```
Sub InsertData()


Dim Proactive, mybook As Worksheet
Dim lCopyLastRow As Long
Dim lDestLastRow As Long

  Set Proactive = Workbooks("Proactive Cleaning_V2.0.1.xlsm").Worksheets("ERROR207")
  Set mybook = Workbooks("ERROR207.csv").Worksheets(1)


  lCopyLastRow = mybook.Cells(wsCopy.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
  lDestLastRow = Proactive.Cells(Proactive.Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp).Offset(1,0).Row

  wsCopy.Range("A2:A" & lCopyLastRow).Copy wsDest.Range("A" & lDestLastRow)
  wsCopy.Range("B2:B" & lCopyLastRow).Copy wsDest.Range("B" & lDestLastRow)


End Sub
```

It seems to work fine when I copy it to a normal cell/column, but when I copy it onto the table columns it just overlaps whatever values are already there, instead of appending it.

(Note: I've found this code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56971952/vba-copying-data-from-one-workbook-to-another-using-lastrow-ranges) and changed it to fit my current code but still doesn't work for me.)

Solution:

```
Sub InsertData()


Dim Proactive, mybook As Worksheet
Dim lCopyLastRow As Long
Dim lDestLastRow As Long
Dim Dte, s As String

  Set Proactive = Workbooks("Proactive Cleaning_V2.0.1.xlsm").Worksheets("ERROR207")
  Set mybook = Workbooks("ERROR207.csv").Worksheets(1)

        lCopyLastRow = mybook.Sheets(1).Cells(mybook.Sheets(1).Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        lDestLastRow = Proactive.Sheets("ERROR207").Cells(Proactive.Sheets("ERROR207").Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
                    
        s = mybook.Name
        Dte = Left(Mid(s, InStr(s, "-") + 8), InStr(Mid(s, InStr(s, "-") + 8), ".") - 1)
        'This will add the date in the file name (assuming the file name is xyz-2021-10-26) to the csv from which the date is pulled
        mybook.Sheets(1).Range("C2:C" & lCopyLastRow).Value = Dte
                    
        'Copy data from csv to xlsm
        mybook.Sheets(1).Range("A2:A" & lCopyLastRow).Copy Proactive.Sheets("ERROR207").Range("A" & lDestLastRow)
        mybook.Sheets(1).Range("B2:B" & lCopyLastRow).Copy Proactive.Sheets("ERROR207").Range("B" & lDestLastRow)
        mybook.Sheets(1).Range("C2:C" & lCopyLastRow).Copy Proactive.Sheets("ERROR207").Range("C" & lDestLastRow)

        'closes csv without saving it
        mybook.Close savechanges:=False

End Sub
```

Also added a way to add a 3rd column with the date based on the file, if anyone needs it!

Comment: You are finding the last row in one sheet and then pasting to a different sheet. This is probably the cause of your problem.

Comment: Figured it out just now, it was on this part:

`lDestLastRow = Proactive.Cells(Proactive.Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp).Offset(1,0).Row`

Had to change the count from 4 to 1, works like a charm now! :D